# How to check the element exist in list with part of the characters

Tags: java

I have arraylist as below

```
{abc/*, abc/xyz/*}
```

Is this possible to find whether the abc/xyz is present in the list?

I tried use contains() but it return true when the full text provided like abc/xyz/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contains method in arraylist will check for exact string match by calling equals method on String hence you can't use contains method. Instead you could use [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method in String by iterating over the list and do something like:

```
for (String str : stringList) {
    if (str.startsWith("abc/xyz")) {//here even you could use contains if you want to find for your pattern anywhere within string.
       System.out.println("I found the string");
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fail for element  `dfd/abc/xyz/*`. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ thanks. I added a comment, to use contains if OP wants in mid string match

Comment: Is this possible to do the same without iterate?

Comment: @Prabhu Sorry. Not possible. Even contains method  do an iteration internally :)

Comment: No its not am afraid.

Comment: @almasshaikh  [who told you that it's not](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ as i said in my answer, its calling equals which is not what OP needs..

Answer (score 0):

Contains only works for full text. You should try [String's indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method. Loop on list and try

```
for (String element: list) {
    if(element.indexOf("abc/xyz")>0){
     return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` can help in this case. Other than this `matches()` can also help.

```
for (String elem : lst) {
  if (elem.matches("abc/xyz.*"))
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

contains() method check for full text,not for regular expression,you can use either indexOf or Pattern API to match with regular expression or consider other API's like `GUAVA` or `Apache common utils`.

```
List<String> getStrings(List<String> list, String regex) {

      List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

      for (String str:list) {
        if (p.matcher(str).matches()) {
          result.add(str);
        }
      }

      return result
    }
```